# Replace a AutoIncrement mysql row with another

Tags: php, mysql

I simply want to reassign one row (from the same table) as the new row 1

The table has column 'version' as AI

three other columns (name,arrayV,notes)

CURRENT FAILED ATTEMPT (just the sql syntax, using fixed values and not variables)

```
UPDATE `variables` AS v1, `variables` AS v2 SET v1.`name` = v2.`name`, v1.`arrayV` = v2.`arrayV`, v1.`notes` = v2.`notes` WHERE v1.`version`=1,v2.`version`= 5;
```

PREVIOUS FAILED ATTEMPTS

```
$newAI1 = $_POST["newSet"];//variable is an integer equal to another row ('version') in table
echo "New set of is ".$newAI1."<br/>";

$sqlMove = "INSERT INTO `variables` (`name`,`arrayV`,`notes`) WHERE `version` = '1' (SELECT `name`,`arrayV`,`notes` FROM `variables` WHERE `version` = '".$newAI1."')";
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: in your insert query table name `variables` is covered with single quote? it must be cover with ` sign

Comment: please define what is version? try something like 
INSERT INTO USER(user_name)  (SELECT user_name FROM USER WHERE id = '13')

Comment: @naeem, `` (backticks) or '' (single quotes), which to use?

Comment: @user12, putting a test integer has no effect, still doesn-t work

Comment: `` have to use @Gamemorize not sigle quotes for column name and tables

Comment: Check you where clause. why you are giving version=1. try without where clause.

Comment: @naeem, replaced using backticks and gave them `` to all four columns, still no luck

Comment: @user12, because i want the row to replace the FIRST ROW

Comment: lets diagnose your query by splitting both queries firstly execute   select query and then execute insert query by giving static values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posibly something like this:

```
$sql = "update `variables` as v1, `variables` as v2 set v1.`name` = v2.`name`, ... where v1.`version`=1 and v2.`version`= '" .$newAI1 . "'"
$sqlDelete = "delete from `variables` where version='" . $newAI1. "'"
```

1) update row 1 with values from row $newAI1

2) delete row $newAI1

Comment: SOLVED... based on your code... the WHERE needed an AND not a ,!

Comment: I put 'and' in the where clause